# How to find the energy of white light?

Tags: optics, energy, visible-light, radiation

If we have a single frequency of light, then the energy associated with that light ray can be given as:

$$ E = h \nu$$

However, white light is a mixture of different frequencies of light in 'some' proportions, so how do we assign an energy for white light?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate incident solar energy on earth in a given day with a spectral filter](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/67380/how-to-calculate-incident-solar-energy-on-earth-in-a-given-day-with-a-spectral-f)  It's not an exact answer but should show you the approach to take

Comment: @CarlWitthoft that question is different because it's not about how to assign energy to a wave of light but rather how to find the total energy released by the sun

Comment: Hmm in that question you reference a source and analyze, here I haven't described a source.

Comment: @Buralan, without a source, you can't define what "white" light is.

Comment: Just calculate it separately for each frequency. Or, put a black sheet of paper in the way and measure the temperature

Answer (score 1):

> However, white light is a mixture of different frequencies of light in
> 'some' proportions, so how do we assign an energy for white light?

We can't attribute an energy to a single 'white photon' by means of:

$$E=h\nu$$

because 'white photons' don't exist.

The only meaningful and useful way to talk about the energy of white light is to talk about the *power* ($\mathrm{W}$) of a source of white light.

Comment: Monochromatic photons don't exist either!

Comment: Power define as $ \frac{E}{t}$ , so how do we define that without energy @Gert

Comment: Actually, $P=\frac{\mathrm{d}E}{\mathrm{d}t}$. Of course you cannot 'define that w/o energy'. You can define the energy of a single photon as $E=h\nu$ OR the *power of a source of white light*. You cannot define the energy of a 'white photon' because that doesn't exist.

Comment: this doesn't address the question.  The correct answer is "integrate $ n(\nu) d\nu $ over the wavelength band involved